# Why after page refresh my redux store is empty?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-middleware

I'am using redux store in my reactjs project.my redux is working properly but when i refresh the browser page my redux store goes empty. is there any way to avoid this.

Comment: That's how all SPA works. U can use `redux-persist` or `redux-storage`

Answer (score 1):

`redux` is used to manage your local state, it doesn't persist the state in local storage, that's why state gets empty when you refresh the page. You can use [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to store the state permanently in local storage of browser.